# Inserting HTML conditionally, taking into account the presence or not of a Sibling

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing field validation of a form, and I want to insert a paragraph, when said condition is met. I have a markup inside a constant, which is inserted into the HTML, on the condition that the next sibling element is not this markup, so that it is only rendered once, and not multiple times. I get this to happen without problems when I start to fill the fields from bottom to top, but the same does not happen when I do it from top to bottom, that is, the condition gives me false, therefore the rendering statement of the paragraph is executed , and as a result I have the same paragraph, many times.

- HTML

  ```
     <div class="upload__column upload__column-2 ">
    <h3 class="upload__heading">Ingredients</h3>
    <!-- <p>Please use format</p> -->
    <label>Ingredient 1</label>
    <input value="0.5,kg,Rice" type="text" required name="ingredient-1"
      placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />

    <label>Ingredient 2</label>
    <input value="1,,Avocado" type="text" name="ingredient-2" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 3</label>
    <input value=",,salt" type="text" name="ingredient-3" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient-4" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 5</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient-5" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 6</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient-6" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  </div>
  ```
- JAVASCRIPT

```
_uploadColumnIng = document.querySelector('.upload__column-2').querySelectorAll('input');

 _addHandlerTakeInputs() {
        const markup = `<div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>`;
        const regExp = /[0-9|f| ]\,(gr|ml|kg)\,[A-z]{4,15}$/i;


        this._uploadColumnIng.forEach(el => el.addEventListener
            ('keyup', function () {
                const inputErr = document.querySelector('.input-err');
                if (regExp.test(el.value)) {
                    if (el.nextElementSibling === inputErr) return;
                    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
                }
            }))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to test the next element

```js
_uploadColumnIng = document.querySelector('.upload__column-2').querySelectorAll('input');


const markup = `<div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>`;
const regExp = /[0-9|f| ]\,(gr|ml|kg)\,[A-z]{4,15}$/i;


this._uploadColumnIng.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keyup', function() {  
  if (!regExp.test(el.value)) {
    if (!el.nextElementSibling || !el.nextElementSibling.matches(".input-err")){
      el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
    }
  }
}));
```

```html
<div class="upload__column upload__column-2 ">
  <h3 class="upload__heading">Ingredients</h3>
  <!-- <p>Please use format</p> -->
  <label>Ingredient 1</label>
  <input value="0.5,kg,Rice" type="text" required name="ingredient-1" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />

  <label>Ingredient 2</label>
  <input value="1,,Avocado" type="text" name="ingredient-2" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <label>Ingredient 3</label>
  <input value=",,salt" type="text" name="ingredient-3" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <label>Ingredient 4</label>
  <input type="text" name="ingredient-4" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <label>Ingredient 5</label>
  <input type="text" name="ingredient-5" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <label>Ingredient 6</label>
  <input type="text" name="ingredient-6" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
</div>
```

But this how I'd actually do it. Have the error messages in place, hidden by CSS. Then toggle an error class on the form element to show them.

```js
_uploadColumnIng = document.querySelector('.upload__column-2').querySelectorAll('input');

const regExp = /[0-9|f| ]\,(gr|ml|kg)\,[A-z]{4,15}$/i;

this._uploadColumnIng.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  el.classList.toggle("error", regExp.test(el.value) );
}));
```

```css
.input-err {display:none;}
.error + .input-err {display:block;}
.error {color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="upload__column upload__column-2 ">
  <h3 class="upload__heading">Ingredients</h3>
  <!-- <p>Please use format</p> -->
  <label>Ingredient 1</label>
  <input value="0.5,kg,Rice" type="text" required name="ingredient-1" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div> 
  <label>Ingredient 2</label>
  <input value="1,,Avocado" type="text" name="ingredient-2" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>
  <label>Ingredient 3</label>
  <input value=",,salt" type="text" name="ingredient-3" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>
  <label>Ingredient 4</label>
  <input type="text" name="ingredient-4" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>
  <label>Ingredient 5</label>
  <input type="text" name="ingredient-5" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>
  <label>Ingredient 6</label>
  <input type="text" name="ingredient-6" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  <div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jon P , thanks for your answer ! I know that it's better to work with hidden by CSS, but i just wanted to do this exercise. Using "matches" worked for the inputs "ingredients-4" and  "ingredients-5" , but for  "ingredients-6" i get this error : **Cannot read property 'matches' of null at HTMLInputElement.** Thanks !

Comment: Little bit of a logic tweak, need to negate the test and check that a sibling exists